# cython create string with nogil

Tags: c++, cython

I would like to create a c++ string in a nogil function in a file that would be cimported via pxd.  If I define, string output = "" or string output = string("blah"), this uses the python interpreter.  Is there a way to define the a string so that the compiler writes in the cython cpp file:

```
std::string val = "blah";
```

Basically have this:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef string my_func() nogil:
   cdef:
      string output = "blah"
  ....
  return output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%%cython -a

#distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef string my_func() nogil:
    cdef:
        char* c_str = 'blah'
        string output = <string>(c_str)
    return output


def py_call():
    return my_func()
```

Then calling `py_call()` gives `b'blah'`, i.e. a bytes object.

**EDIT:** Here's the generated C++ code:

```
+08:         char* c_str = 'blah'
  __pyx_v_c_str = ((char *)"blah");
+09:         string output = <string>(c_str)
  __pyx_v_output = ((std::string)__pyx_v_c_str);
```

So it literally casts `char*` to `std::string`.

An alternative is then to invoke the constructor from `char*`:

```
cdef:
    char* c_str = 'blah'
    string output = string(c_str)
```

which generates

```
+08:         char* c_str = 'blah'
  __pyx_v_c_str = ((char *)"blah");
+09:         string output = string(c_str, 4)
  try {
    __pyx_t_1 = std::string(__pyx_v_c_str, 4);
  } catch(...) {
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    PyGILState_STATE __pyx_gilstate_save = PyGILState_Ensure();
    #endif
    __Pyx_CppExn2PyErr();
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
    #endif
    __PYX_ERR(0, 9, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_v_output = __pyx_t_1;
```

which looks better.